# Find records with a value greater than another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, prisma

I need to find rows using Prisma in Postgresql that match certain criteria where one property has a greater value than certain other properties in the same record.

Something along the lines of this (please forgive my rusty SQL):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Analysis 
WHERE property_1 > property_2;
```

Here is the model:

```
model Analysis {
  id                    Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
  property_1            Int
  property_2            Int
  property_3            Int
  property_4            Int
}
```

So for example, a query could be to return all records where `property_1` is greater than `property_2`; or where `property_2` is greater than `property_3` and `property_4`.

If I had a constant value (like 10, for example), it could be relatively simple; something like this:

```
    const analyses = await prisma.analysis.findMany({
      where: {
        property_1: {
          gt: 10
        }
      }
    })
```

But obviously this is different, because it needs to be a variable property in the record itself. In this example, how would we replace `10` with `property_2`?

I've tried `gt: analysis.property_2`, but of course that doesn't work, because `analysis` is undefined.

Is this even possible with Prisma's API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Prisma version >=4.3.0 only.`

add this to client generator

```
generator client {
  provider        = "..."
  previewFeatures = ["fieldReference"]
}
```

Now you can reference fields in where object.

```
const analyses = await prisma.analysis.findMany({
  where: {
    property_1: {
      gt: prisma.analysis.fields.property_2
    }
  }
})
```

[more in the docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#compare-columns-in-the-same-table)